# how to install and use ios simulator with adf mobile?

Tags: ios, xcode, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

i want work with ios simulator, for that i  have download xcode 6 with extension .DMG  .
Any one have idea how to install this simulator and how use it with adf mobile (jdevloper) in Windows platform?

help me please?

Comment: You can not, the iOS Simulator requires OS X to run.

Comment: but why oracle include ios in jdeveloper configuration , if is not possible to configure ios on windows or linux platforms (jdev exist just for linux and windows platforms but not mac os)

Comment: See my answer, it is not possible in any other OS then OSX. And JDeveloper is available for OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#BABCIAHF):

> **3.2.1 What You Need to Create an Application**
>
> Before you start creating an ADF Mobile application for iOS, ensure
>   that you have the following available:
>
> - A computer running Mac OS X
> - Oracle JDeveloper (see [Section 3.3, "Setting Up JDeveloper"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#BABICBCJ)).
> - Oracle JDeveloper extension for ADF Mobile (see [Section 3.3, "Setting Up JDeveloper"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#BABICBCJ))
> - Xcode (see [Section 3.4.1,"How to Install Xcode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#CHDBAHEF)")
> - iOS SDK (see [Section 3.4.2, "How to Install iOS SDK"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#CHDFBCDI))
>
> For more information, see [Section 3.4, "Setting Up
>   Development Tools for iOS Platform."](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/setup.htm#BABCGGIG)